# Отобразить несколько кривых на одной координатной плоскости по дискретному набору точек Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, график

День добрый, у меня есть дискретный набор данных по оси x_distance и y_speed. Каждая такая пара {x_distance,y_speed} характеризует один график. Необходимо построить на одной координатной плоскости несколько таких графиков (до 1000 шт.) при условии что x_distance и y_speed имеют разные значения для разных кривых. Есть пример кода, который я сейчас сделала (dict_value - это словарь значений, пусть вас не смущает):

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
x_distance = list(map(float, dict_value[1][4]))# вектор расстояния
y_speed = list(map(float,dict_value[1][3])) # вектор скорости

#сглаживание функции интерполированием
xi = np.linspace(float(x_distance[0]), float(x_distance[-1]), 10) # промежуточных значение
f_interpold=interp1d(x_distance,y_speed,kind='cubic') #создание функции с помощью кубического интерполирования

# отрисовка графиков зависимости скорости от расстояния
title_graph = 'The graph of the train speed \n depending on the distance \n for the sequence №' + str(1)
name_pictures = 'Plot' + str(1)
ax1.plot(x_distance, y_speed, 'go', xi, f_interpold(xi), '-',label='Using set_dashes()')

for i in range(1,4):#попвтка построить график для трех кривых
    ax = ax1.twiny()
    x_distance = list(map(float, dict_value[i][4]))# вектор расстояния
    y_speed = list(map(float,dict_value[i][3])) # вектор скорости
    xi = np.linspace(float(x_distance[0]), float(x_distance[-1]), 10) # промежуточных значение
    f_interpold=interp1d(x_distance,y_speed,kind='cubic') #создание функции с помощью кубического интерполирования

    # отрисовка графиков зависимости скорости от расстояния
    name_pictures = 'Plot' + str(i)
    ax.plot(x_distance, y_speed, 'go', label='Using set_dashes()')
    ax.set(xlabel='distance (m)', ylabel='speed (V)', title=title_graph)

plt.show()
```

При компиляции я получаю следующую картину:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

по оси y_speed точки расположились верно, а по x_distance - не верно касательно значений оси. К тому же почему-то Plot в цикле не сработал. Подскажите пожалуйста как я могу исправить эту ошибку. Заранее благодарю

Comment: можете привести в вопросе примеры данных для нескольких графиков?

Comment: даже если построите 30+ графиков на одной координатной плоскости, то разобраться где какой график будет практически невозможно. При 100+ графиках - получится просто "каша"...